# database join questions

Tags: java, mysql, database

there are two tables in db

```
Book{
isbn integer, //primary key
title char(50),
publisher char(30),
year integer
}

Author{
isbn integer,  //foreign key 
name String,
rank integer,  // indicate whether it is author1, author2, author3,...,authorn
}
```

write a sql statement to output book in this way
Title
  author1
  author2
publisher, year.

The logic is selecting two records from Author table according to isbn then combine to the record in Book and output it. I think we can do it in MySQL?

THANKS.

Comment: Can `author1 author2` be one column?

Comment: what about author3,...,authorn? don't you need those?

Comment: Are we supposed to answer what are clearly college homework questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT b.title, group_concat(a.name separator ',')
FROM book b join author a on b.isbn = a.isbn
group by b.title
```

Comment: select b.title, group_concat(a.name order by a.rank limit 2) as Author from Book b join Author a on b.isbn = a.isbn order by b.title.  Still needs it come up with Author1 and Author2

Comment: To produce Author1  Author2 . . . . AuthorN as column headings you could use a procedure as shown in this article http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html

Comment: Another method of producing Author1 Author2 . . . AuthorN as column headings would be to first query the number of Authors and then construct the needed SQL statement at run time.

Comment: right, I prefer the second solution, but if I write ... group_concat(a.name order by a.rank limit 2)... I always get a syntext error around limit 2. Looks like I cant add limit 2 within group_concat

Comment: Apparently limit within a group_concat is not supported. It was submitted as a feature request twice. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30098  and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12544

Comment: here is my way SELECT
Book.title,
(SELECT Author.`name` FROM Author WHERE Author.isbn = Book.isbn AND Author.rank = '1') AS `author1`,
(SELECT Author.`name` FROM Author WHERE Author.isbn = Book.isbn AND Author.rank = '2') AS `author2`
FROM
Book

Comment: That works fine if you only have to deal with 2 Authors, but based on your original question I thought you had to handle an arbitrary number of Authors

Comment: Right, actually, the requirement of the interview question is not very clear. And it might have case like: in the author table, we have authors with rank2 and rank3 but we dont have rank1, we just let rank1 empty. So, I think this solution is ok assuming I always output first and second author of the book

Answer (score 0):

There are two sub query in my solution: SELECT Book.title, (SELECT Author.name FROM Author WHERE Author.isbn = Book.isbn AND Author.rank = '1') AS author1, (SELECT Author.name FROM Author WHERE Author.isbn = Book.isbn AND Author.rank = '2') AS author2 FROM Book;

is there any way to improve performance? using, join, procedure, or other way? thanks